Question in the Activities of Brahman
According to Shri Adi Shankaracharya's Advaita vedanta the Saguna Brahman of prativasika satya is the active God who creates, protects, and destroys the cosmos. Saguna Brahman is therefore active. His differentiation between the Saguna Brahman (whose real nature is nirguna Brahman) and Nirguna Brahman reveals his belief that the Nirguna Brahman cannot be active. According to Advaita, nirguna Brahman is immutable. Therefore, Shri Adi Sankaracharya seems to argue that since Brahman is immutable, Brahman cannot be active in reality because activity and immutability are incompatible attributes, i.e. they cannot exist together in one level of reality.
Does Shri Adi Shankaracharya explicitly say that Nirguna Brahman cannot be active because of its immutable nature? If so what are those verses?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

While there are many places in the Bhashyas of Shankaracharya for the topic of 'Brahman is immutable and hence no action can be attributed to it', here is a discussion that brings out Shankara's logic on the topic:  Brahma sutra bhashya 4.3.14.  The English translation of the following Bhashya can be accessed from Swami Gambhirananda's translation:
The gist of the Bhashya is: The Shruti passages such as the Shvetashwatara which say that 'Brahman is nishkalam (no parts), nishkriyam (no action), not short, not long, not atomic, etc. preclude any real activity in Brahman. For, only a person endowed with body, organs, mind, etc. can act. Brahman is devoid of all these as per Shruti passages. But what about the passages which declare 'All this creation is from Brahman, it rests in Brahman and lapses in Brahman'? For that Shankara says: these passages are meant to teach the true nature of Brahman and therefore do not convey the meaning they literally seem to.  So the discussion goes on. One will benefit from reading the entire discussion in English, if needed, from Swami Gambhirnanda's translation which can be accessed online too:
https://archive.org/details/brahma-sutra-bhasya-of-sankaracarya-translated-by-swami-gambhirananda/page/882/mode/1up   See p.885 second para onwards.  The exact English part for the Sanskrit cited below.
ननु लोके गतस्यापि गन्तव्यता देशान्तरविशिष्टस्य दृष्टा — यथा पृथिवीस्थ एव पृथिवीं देशान्तरद्वारेण गच्छति, तथा अनन्यत्वेऽपि बालस्य कालान्तरविशिष्टं वार्धकं स्वात्मभूतमेव गन्तव्यं दृष्टम् , तद्वत् ब्रह्मणोऽपि सर्वशक्त्युपेतत्वात् कथञ्चित् गन्तव्यता स्यादिति — न, प्रतिषिद्धसर्वविशेषत्वाद्ब्रह्मणः । ‘निष्कलं निष्क्रियं शान्तं निरवद्यं निरञ्जनम्’ (श्वे. उ. ६ । १९) ‘अस्थूलमनण्वह्रस्वमदीर्घम्’ (बृ. उ. ३ । ८ । ८) ‘सबाह्याभ्यन्तरो ह्यजः’ (मु. उ. २ । १ । २) ‘स वा एष महानज आत्माजरोऽमरोऽमृतोऽभयो ब्रह्म’ (बृ. उ. ४ । ४ । २५) ‘स एष नेति नेत्यात्मा’ (बृ. उ. ३ । ९ । २६) इत्यादिश्रुतिस्मृतिन्यायेभ्यो न देशकालादिविशेषयोगः परमात्मनि कल्पयितुं शक्यते, येन भूप्रदेशवयोवस्थान्यायेनास्य गन्तव्यता स्यात् । भूवयसोस्तु प्रदेशावस्थादिविशेषयोगादुपपद्यते देशकालविशिष्टा गन्तव्यता । जगदुत्पत्तिस्थितिप्रलयहेतुत्वश्रुतेरनेकशक्तित्वं ब्रह्मण इति चेत् , न, विशेषनिराकरणश्रुतीनामनन्यार्थत्वात् । उत्पत्त्यादिश्रुतीनामपि समानमनन्यार्थत्वमिति चेत् , न, तासामेकत्वप्रतिपादनपरत्वात् । मृदादिदृष्टान्तैर्हि सतो ब्रह्मण एकस्य सत्यत्वं विकारस्य च अनृतत्वं प्रतिपादयत् शास्त्रं नोत्पत्त्यादिपरं भवितुमर्हति ॥
कस्मात्पुनरुत्पत्त्यादिश्रुतीनां विशेषनिराकरणश्रुतिशेषत्वम् , न पुनरितरशेषत्वमितरासामिति, उच्यते — विशेषनिराकरणश्रुतीनां निराकाङ्क्षार्थत्वात् । न हि आत्मन एकत्वनित्यत्वशुद्धत्वाद्यवगतौ सत्यां भूयः काचिदाकाङ्क्षा उपजायते, पुरुषार्थसमाप्तिबुद्ध्युपपत्तेः, ‘तत्र को मोहः कः शोक एकत्वमनुपश्यतः’ (ई. उ. ७) ‘अभयं वै जनक प्राप्तोऽसि’ (बृ. उ. ४ । २ । ४) ‘विद्वान्न बिभेति कुतश्चन । एतꣳ ह वाव न तपति । किमहꣳ साधु नाकरवम् । किमहं पापमकरवम्’ (तै. उ. २ । ९ । १) इत्यादिश्रुतिभ्यः, तथैव च विदुषां तुष्ट्यनुभवादिदर्शनात् , विकारानृताभिसन्ध्यपवादाच्च — ‘मृत्योः स मृत्युमाप्नोति य इह नानेव पश्यति’ इति । अतो न विशेषनिराकरणश्रुतीनामन्यशेषत्वमवगन्तुं शक्यते । नैवमुत्पत्त्यादिश्रुतीनां निराकाङ्क्षार्थप्रतिपादनसामर्थ्यमस्ति । प्रत्यक्षं तु तासामन्यार्थत्वं समनुगम्यते । तथा हि — ‘तत्रैतच्छुङ्गमुत्पतितꣳ सोम्य विजानीहि नेदममूलं भविष्यति’ (छा. उ. ६ । ८ । ३) इत्युपन्यस्य उदर्के सत एवैकस्य जगन्मूलस्य विज्ञेयत्वं दर्शयति; ‘यतो वा इमानि भूतानि जायन्ते । येन जातानि जीवन्ति । यत्प्रयन्त्यभिसंविशन्ति । तद्विजिज्ञासस्व । तद्ब्रह्म’ (तै. उ. ३ । १ । १) इति च । एवमुत्पत्त्यादिश्रुतीनाम् ऐकात्म्यावगमपरत्वात् नानेकशक्तियोगो ब्रह्मणः । अतश्च गन्तव्यत्वानुपपत्तिः । ‘न तस्य प्राणा उत्क्रामन्ति’ (बृ. उ. ४ । ४ । ६) ‘ब्रह्मैव सन्ब्रह्माप्येति’ इति च परस्मिन्ब्रह्मणि गतिं निवारयति । तद्व्याख्यातम् ‘स्पष्टो ह्येकेषाम्’ (ब्र. सू. ४ । २ । १३) इत्यत्र ॥

Thank you very much, especially for the link to the English translation :)

There is a reason given by Sri Sankaracharya why the Self which is Brahman in Advaita Vedanta can't take part in any action. The reason given is that in case of action Self will be subject to impermanence.

Vedantin: No, since the Self cannot reasonably be the sphere of any
action, for no action can take place without bringing about some
change in its locus. But if the Self changes through action, It will
be subject to impermanence, and that will militate against such texts
as, "It is said to be immutable" (Gita II.25). And that is
undesirable. Hence the Self can have no action occurring on Itself..
And action taking place on something else, cannot purify the Self,
which is not an object thereof.

Brahma Sutra Bhasya I.i.4 of Sri Sankaracharya translated by Swami Gambhirananda

ধন্যবাদ ভাই। আমি বইটি দেখে নেব

Hello Pradip, activity and STRICT immutability are not contradictory and can coexist in the same level of reality. This follows from the Shri Adi Sankaracharya's swaroop lakshana. The swaroop lakshana "satyam, jnanam, anantam, Brahman" shows that there is no reason to differentiate it from the tataksha lakshana which describes activity because by studying the nature of uncountable infinity one can see that infinity (anantam) allows activity and strict immutability to coexist in harmony. This coexistence is at the heart of Shri Madhvacharya's Brahma Sutra Bhasya and Tatvavaad

Shri Madhvacharya taught the true nature of infinity and the swaroop lakshana in his Dwaita school several centuries before the European mathematicians (like Cantor, etc) independently and rigorously developed the mathematical nature of uncountable infinity. Thus Shri Madhvacharya and his ideas cannot be trivialized as lower-rung ideas which many swamis in Kolkata (like those in the Ramakrishna mission) ignorantly do. Shri Madhva does not make the logical error found in the Advaitic school's Brahma Sutra Bhasya.

This reflects Shri Madhvacharya's divinity as Lord Hanuman and reveals he truly visited Lord Veda Vyas. Humans can make mistakes like not understanding the true nature of uncoutable infinity in the 700s AD but Lord Veda Vyas would not make such a mistake and neither would an exalted devata like the Ruju devatas, of whom Shri Madhvacharya was Lord Mukhyaprana, the main pratima of Lord Vishnu.

And the exalted devata Lord Shiva, the son of Lord Brahma,  would not make such a mistake either. Therefore, to me it seems that it is highly unlikely that Advaita was propounded by Lord Shiva in order to rescue Sanatan Dharma, which is claimed in Shri Vidyaranya Madhavacharya's Sankara Vijaya, a biography composed 600 years after the demise of Shri Ādi Sankarāchāryā. I AM SORRY  if that hurts any sentiments. I am NOT trying to hurt YOU  but I think it is important to objectively & logically understand Advaita's past and distill the historical from the hagiographical. Blind faith is dangerous.

Scripture alone can tell us the true nature of reality. How do we know what scripture and commentary are the true ones? Those that are logically flawless alone can be true. Anumana pramana serves to identify the true Sabdha pramana.

I added citations from Shri Madhvacharya's works here that showed his understanding of the swaroop lakshana: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/60178/refuting-sa-atma-atat-tvam-asi-of-madhava-paingala-upanishad/60282#60282

Dhanyabad lekhagulor janya.

Coming from a dwaitin..there is no nirguna brahman and saguna brahman(seperate) there is only one Brahman who is inconcievable or achintya..
Gita 7.24
अव्यक्तं व्यक्तिमापन्नं मन्यन्ते मामबुद्धय: |
परं भावमजानन्तो ममाव्ययमनुत्तमम् || 24||
The less intelligent think that I, the Supreme Lord Shree Krishna, was formless earlier and have now assumed this personality. They do not understand the imperishable exalted nature of My personal form.
Now coming to immutability..Brahman is not a static thing or active thing it is inconceivable and can only be experienced..It is not some void or sea..brahman is a person..to speak correctly it is Brahma(Narayana)..so is a living person immutable? Active or static?

Umm you need more scriptural proof from Advaitan texts! :)

@aryaninvader Thank you for your answer; however, I was asking what Shri Adi Sankaracharya's explicit logic was to differentiate between tataksha lakshana and swaroop lakshana (see his comments under second verse of Brahma sutras), not whether his philosophy represents the Vedic philosophy (that's a wholly different topic/question :D ).

You're Welcome.
