Refuting 'Sa Atma Atat Tvam Asi' of Madhava: Paingala Upanishad
In his commentary, Madhava very ingeniously uses rules of grammar to twist 'Sa atmaatatvamasi' to 'Sa atma atat twam asi'. Here Atmatatvam asi, the a is bifurcated to a+a. This is actually fine with grammar but raises the question of overcomplication of a simple statement to suit one's philosophy.
However, Paingala Upanishad (Chapter 3) quotes the four Mahavakyas as,
अथ हैनं पैङ्गलः प्रपच्छ याज्ञवल्क्यं महावाक्यविवरणमनुब्रूहीति .
स होवाच याज्ञवल्क्यस्तत्त्वमसि त्वं तदसि त्वं ब्रह्मास्यहं ब्रह्मास्मीत्यनुसन्धानं कुर्यात् .
Here, Tat Tvam Asi is clearly written as it is, Yajnavalkyas Tat Tvam Asi. There is no scope of using grammar to break it down. Thus Paingala through cross reference points out the way in which Vedantic Rishis wanted the mahavakya to be used. Paingala Upanishad is certainly an ancient and authentic text as it has been cited by Adi Shankara himself.
This really puts Madhava's interpretation in a very tough spot to defend. Wanted to know what do Madhava Dvaitins think on this?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


At the outset, I like to pay my respects to Shri Adi Shankaracharya and the Advaita acharyas of the four mutts, both present and past. Although I am deeply humbled by their vast knowledge of Vedic verses, I can no longer accept Advaita as the highest, non-sublatable philosophy of Sanatan Dharma nor can I accept the accuracy of the Sankara-Vijaya of Vidyaranya. I like to give a special thanks to Shri Nischalananda Saraswati of Govardhana Peetham (my favorite Advaita guru) for his sincere love for Bharata and mathematics. My response might be of special interest to his affinity towards mathematics.
I would also like to pay my respects to Lord Ved Vyasa, Maa Lakshmi, Lord Mukhyaprana and Lord Brahma, Maa Bharati and Maa Savitri, Lord Rudra and Maa Parvati, various other devatas and divine beings, and to all the Dwaita gurus. While it is admissible to debate the tenets and arguments of a system, it is wholly unacceptable to call a great man who wished to reestablish the ultimate reality of theistic devotion a liar and a con-man. It is a symptom of a pure heart filled with true devotion and jnana to reject any philosophy that says one's love for God does not ultimately exist. I like to humbly defend Madhva-shastra and reveal some of my reasons why I transitioned from Advaita to Dwaita. All of the reasons outlined below are due to the grace of the Param Atma alone. As a man who has been an Advaitin for most of his life, I will primarily confine my arguments to shabda and anumana pramanas. May the Lord, His foremost Son Shri Hanumana-Bhima-Madhva, and all devatas be pleased with it.
Shri Hari-Vayu Gurubhyo Namah

I. The logical foundation of Advaita's (the Purvapaksha's) interpretation of the Upanishads.
Let us start by considering verse 2.12 of the Bhagavad Gita.


न त्वेवाहं जातु नासं न त्वं नेमे जनाधिपाः |
न चैव न भविष्याम: सर्वे वयमत: परम् || 12||




na tvevāhaṁ jātu nāsaṁ na tvaṁ neme janādhipāḥ
na chaiva na bhaviṣhyāmaḥ sarve vayamataḥ param




“Never was there a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor all these kings; nor in the future shall any of us cease to be.”


The literal meaning of this verse is clear and at first the verse seems to suggest that every individual in the battlefield and the Supreme Lord Sri Krishna are eternal and separate beings; however, is this the intended meaning of the verse and all of the Upanishads? This question has been a bone of contention among the various schools of philosophy and the philosophers of the Vedanta tradition. On one side of the debate are the Advaitins, otherwise known as the non-dualists, who staunchly disagree with the claim that the literal meaning is the intended transcendental meaning of this verse. On this side of the debate belong the commentaries of Sri Adi Shankaracharya and Sri Madhusudan Saraswati, the great devotee of Lord Krishna who later accepted Advaita Vedanta to be the intended meaning of all of the Upanishads. Sri Adi Shankaracharya, in his commentary on the Bhagavad Gita, interprets this verse as follows:


“The idea is that in all three divisions of time we are eternal and as identical with the [Atma]. The plural number in verse 12 refers to differences in respect of bodies; it does not refer to a plurality of [Atmas].” (A.G. Krishna Warrier, p. 29)


In other words, Sri Adi Shankaracharya takes the position that the verse really implies monism: the Atma alone exists and our real identity is not the non-absolute personality, the ahamkara, but the Supreme Brahman. According to Sri Shankaracharya the ahamkara is a consequence of Brahman powering the intellect. The everyday individual personality is an effect that arises due to Brahman. This is explained nicely in verses 20 and 25 of Sri Shankaracharya's Atmabodha (translated by Swami Chinmay Ananda):


“Depending upon the Ᾱtman, which is of the nature of Consciousness, the body, senses, mind and intellect engage themselves in their respective activities, just as men work depending upon the light of the sun.” (Verse 20)




“By the indiscriminate blending of the two, the Existence-Consciousness aspects of the Atman and the thought wave of the intellect, there arises the notion of ‘I know’.” (Verse 25)


According to Advaita Vedanta, the everyday experience of mundane duality is not the ultimate reality. The ultimate reality is just one being, Brahman, and does not consist of multiple individual beings that are distinct from Brahman. Only the non-absolute reality of everyday experience involves a Supreme Being, i.e. Ishwara, and subordinate beings, the Jivas, but from the ultimate perspective, all of this is the activities of one being, the Brahman of the Upanishads. This is also summarized in verses 32-34 of Shri Adi Shankaracharya's Tattva Bhoda:



Doubt:- But the Jiva is endowed with ego and his knowledge is limited (whereas) Isvara, is without ego and is omniscient. How, then, can there be identity, as stated in the Mahavakya TAT TWAM ASI (That Thou Art), between these two who are possessed of contradictory characteristics?






No (it is not so). The literal meaning of the word ‘Thou’ is the one who identifies himself with gross and subtle bodies (i.e. Jiva). The implied meaning of the word ‘Thou’ is pure awareness which is free from all conditionings and which is appreciated in the state of ‘Samadhi’






So also the literal meaning of the word ‘That’ is the Isvara having omniscience etc. The implied meaning of the word ‘That’ is the pure awareness free of all conditionings.



In verse 32, Shri Adi Shankaracharya expresses a doubt that may appear in a student’s mind: How can the verse “That Thou Art” equate two different beings, the limited Jiva and the omniscient Ishvara? In other words, how can there be strict oneness with a supreme entity who is one without a second? To this self-created enquiry, Shri Adi Shankaracharya responds by noting that one must remove the literal meaning of “That” and “Thou,” i.e. one must remove the notion that the verse “Tat Tvam Asi” is revealing the relationship between two distinct entities, one inferior and another superior. Thus according to Shri Adi Shankaracharya, the verse “Tat Tvam Asi” makes no sense if one, incorrectly, tries to read it as a verse equating two distinct entities. The principle logic introduced in these verses of the Tattva Bodha is the following: strict oneness and a supreme entity cannot describe the relationship between two distinct and separate entities, one inferior and one superior; they must imply nonduality, i.e. that Brahman alone exists. This logic is at the base of the non-dualistic interpretations of Shri Adi Shankaracharya and he uses this logic to interpret the Mahavakyas "Tat Tvam Asi," "Aham Brahmasmi," and "Ayam Atma Brahma."
What are the consequences of this logic? Swami Vireshwarananda, a prominent and respectable Advaitin (and person), finishes his introduction to the Sri Bhasya of Sri Ramanujacharya as follows:


“The Upanishads, as already stated at the very beginning, do not teach any particular doctrine. They teach various doctrines suited to different people at different stages of spiritual evolution. They are not contradictory, but based on the principle of individual fitness for receiving a truth (Adhikaribheda). The aspirants are taken step by step to the ultimate truth, from dualism to qualified monism and finally to monism. “That thou Art” is the last word of the Upanishads in religion. The Brahma-Sutras also are as comprehensive as the Upanishads and contain references to these various stages. Hence, commentators, when they claim that their commentary alone is correct, do not reflect Badarayana’s view truly.” (p. lxxix)


His words reflect the unified consensus among Advaitins that the philosophy propounded by the Upanishads can only be unified through stratification and that the various contradictory verses refer to various “stages of spiritual evolution,” which is a different way to express Sri Adi Shankaracharya's concept of gradual liberation (Krama Mukti). Their mantra is "different slokas are for different folks." The reason why they teach that the Upanishads “teach various doctrines” and the fully-matured spiritualist arrives “finally to monism” is because they firmly believe that strict oneness and a supreme entity cannot imply the relationships between two distinct entities. This is the fundamental reasoning that is at the base of Advaita Vedanta.
II. Verses that truly describe the absolute, non-sublatable Brahman in Advaita
Sri Adi Sankaracharya writes the following in his Brahma Sutra Bhasya (see copy on hinduscriptures.in):


"Meditation on the Saguna Brahman cannot lead to immediate liberation. It can at best lead to gradual liberation (Krama-Mukti). The knowledge of the Nirguna Brahman alone leads to immediate liberation. Now in many places of the Upanishads, Brahman is apparently described by qualifying adjuncts; yet scriptures say that knowledge of that Brahman [i.e. the one described by qualifying adjuncts, or the Saguna Brahman] leads to liberation. If Brahman is worshiped as limited by those adjuncts, it cannot lead to such Liberation. But if these qualifying adjuncts are regarded as not ultimately aimed at by the Sruti, but used merely as indicative of Brahman, then these very texts would refer to the nirguna Brahman and liberation would be the very result of knowing that Brahman. So by reasoning we have to arrive at a conclusion as to the significance of these texts, which obviously have a doubtful import" (Brahma Sutra commentary, verse 1.11).


What verses truly describe the absolute, non-sublatable Brahman according to Shri Adi Shankaracharya? He writes the following in his Sutra Bhasya:


"The scriptures give another definition of Brahman which describes Its true nature: 'Truth, Knowledge, Infinity, Brahman.'  This is called the Swaroop Lakshana, that which defines Brahman in Its true essence." (Brahma Sutra commentary, verse 1.1.2).


The key verse to understand the import of the Vedas is "satyam, jnanam, anantam, Brahman." Therefore, the Vedas, when discussing ultimate reality, must speak in the language of infinity.
III. Understanding the language of infinity
Consider two sets X and Y. Let X be the uncountable set of real numbers between a and b where a < b. Let Y be the uncountable set of all real numbers from negative infinity to positive infinity. Modern mathematics (see this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kf2Xwr22oGM to understand why) has shown that the number of numbers in set X is strictly one with the number of numbers in set Y, yet there are infinitely additional numbers in Y that are not in X. Hence the relationship between X and Y is of simultaneous strict quantitative oneness and strict quantitative difference. Let j be the imaginary number and let Z be the set of pure imaginary numbers between aj and bj (multiplication sign) where a < b. Again, the relationship between Z and Y is of simultaneous strict quantitative oneness and strict quantitative difference.
Now let us consider verse 15.7 of the Bhagavad Gita:


ममैवांशो जीवलोके जीवभूत: सनातन: |
मन:षष्ठानीन्द्रियाणि प्रकृतिस्थानि कर्षति || 7||




mamaivānśho jīva-loke jīva-bhūtaḥ sanātanaḥ
manaḥ-ṣhaṣhṭhānīndriyāṇi prakṛiti-sthāni karṣhati


The Jiva Atma is the amsa of the Param Atma. Amsa does not have to mean "part." For instance a child is called an amsa of his father but that does not mean that the child is a part of his parent's being. The child is a separate being who has some physical and behavioral similarities with his parent but has some differences as well. Notice that the set X is a subset (i.e. part) of Y while Z is not a subset of Y. Yet Z is uncountably infinite like Y and therefore is an amsa of Y without being a part of Y. Notice that the set Z can be bounded by finite numbers while the set Y can never be bounded by any number. Being bounded is akin to inferiority and being unbounded is akin to superiority. Let Z represent a Jiva Atma and Y represent the Param Atma. The relationship between the Jiva Atma and the Param Atma is that of simultaneous strict quantitative oneness (Tat Tvam Asi) and strict quantitative difference (A Tat Tvam Asi) without one being a part, i.e. bodily attribute or shakti, of the other (i.e no non-duality). Since infinity is associated with truth, these are experienced by a liberated Jiva Atma, up to his capacity, when he gives up his linga sharira at the end of Lord Brahma's 100 years.
In the pluralistic-monistic philosophies that proclaim ultimate reality is "non-dual in essence," the corresponding model would be as follows: Param Atma is the set Y and the Jiva Atma is the set X (i.e. it is a part of Param Atma as His bodily attributes or shaktis). Manifestations of infinity must be maximized in absolute reality. Since infinity is associated with satya, or truth, a reality that has less manifestations of truth (i.e. infinity) than another reality cannot be called absolute reality. The more additional manifestations the better. Our version of absolute reality mentions that each attribute/shakti/part of Brahman is strictly one with and different from another attribute/shakti/part of Brahman, just like the version a pluralistic-monist can incorporate in his philosophy, but also mentions that each Jiva, who is not His feature, is strictly one with and different from another Jiva and Brahman, which the pluralistic-monist cannot incorporate in his philosophy without ruining monism. Hence the Dwaita version of ultimate reality has additional features of satya than the monism ones.
Since infinity is associated with truth in the swaroop lakshana, it cannot be sublated. Hence the Advaitin's swaroop lakshana reveals duality cannot be sublated and that strict oneness, strict difference, the existence of superiority and inferiority coexist in harmony in absolute reality. From this analysis we see that sabdha and anumana pramanas reveal that prataksha is a paramarthmik pramana. Duality is ultimately real, the external world exists independently of our perception of it, and what we see is really occurring independently of our perception of it; however, how we see the external world depends on perception and there can be significant misperceptions.
Are the various unknown and mysterious verses that Shri Madhvacharya quotes to support duality at odds with the Upanishads? Were they simply made up and was Shri Madhvacharya a liar and a con-man? The Advaitin's own swaroop lakshana defends the claim that Shri Madhva's sources were genuine because the swaroop lakshana reveals that Shri Madhva's duality that is against pluralistic monism is an aspect of ultimate reality.
Other supporting verses are the following. They reveal that ultimate reality is free from pairs of opposites, i.e. concepts that seem incompatible in everyday experience harmoniously coexist in ultimate reality. These are inextricably associated with "satyam, jnanam, anantam, Brahman":

The Maitreya Upanishad. These verses are the words spoken by Brahman:



III-4. I am devoid of honor and dishonor, I am nirguna, I am Shiva, I am free from Dwaita and Advaita, I am free from the pairs (of opposites), I am He.




III-5. I am devoid of being and non-being, I am beyond speech, I am effulgence, I am the power of the void (zero) and the non-void (non-zero) and I am the auspicious and the inauspicious (i.e. beyond both of them).




III-7. I am beyond the number one and I am beyond the number two as well. I am above the distinction of good and bad and I am devoid of ideation.




III-19. I am free of space and time, I am the bliss of the principal unclad sages, I am beyond ‘there is’ and ‘there is not’ and I am devoid of all negation.




III-22. I am above the body and its dweller and I am unique, (nirguna). I am beyond liberation, I am liberated and I am always devoid of final emancipation.



Chapter 1, Verse 36 of the  Avadhoota  Gita spoken by Lord Dattatreya, an incarnation of Ishwara Param Atma.



Some seek nonduality, others duality. They do not know the Truth, which is the same at all times and everywhere, which is devoid of both duality and nonduality (i.e. devoid of any sense of contradiction that strict difference and strict oneness might suggest ).


IV. Conclusion
The fundamental logic of the Advaitins when they interpret Tat Tvam Asi, which is "strict oneness and a supreme entity cannot describe the relationship between two distinct and separate entities, one inferior and one superior; they must imply nonduality, i.e. that Brahman alone exists" is incorrect. Advaita Vedanta is the philosophy that does not understand its own swaroop lakshana and the logical base of the philosophy is flawed and therefore can safely be ignored. By using the nondualists’ swaroop lakshana, we have shown that the strict oneness mentioned in, for instance, the verses “Tat Tvam Asi (You are That)” and “Ahaṁ Brahmāsmi (I am Brahman),” strict difference, and the existence of superiority and inferiority are complementary and thus Brahman cannot be neglected because He is superior to all of the Jiva Atmas. Thus we, by virtue of the swaroop lakshana, go from “Ahaṁ Brahmāsmi (I am Brahman)” to “Aheyam Brahmāsmi (Brahman, whose knowledge is ever-existing (asmi), cannot be neglected)” and from "Tat Tvam Asi" to "A Tat Tvam Asi." The final understanding is Shri Madhvacharya's interpretation and therefore Shri Madhvacharya's shastra is THE Vedanta.
V. The Teachings of the Chandogya Upanishads and the Other Principal Upanishads:
In the Chandogya Upanishad the phrase “Saatmaatattvamasi” is meant to show that in the ultimate reality strict oneness, strict difference, the existence of eternal superiority and inferiority, etc coexist in harmony. Hence the cleverly deliberate grammatical construction. This phrase therefore teaches the relationship between the Jiva Atma and the Param Atma and reflects the nature of infinity and the swaroop lakshana “satyam, jnanam, anantam, Brahman.” The Chandogya Upanishad’s teachings, as well as those of the other Principal Upanishads, serve to reveal this non-sublatable truth to the student of the Vedanta. Since “Saatmaatattvamasi” is meant to teach the strict difference between the Supreme Lord and the individual Jiva Atma, which is not obvious to some, Shri Madhvacharya cited the appropriate source that tells one how to read the Chandogya Upanishad and get a correct understanding of a facet of ultimate reality. Without knowing the correct reading from this source, one will get an incorrect understand of ultimate reality that does not reflect the nature of the swaroop lakshana.
However, the Chandogya Upanishad does not teach another facet of the swaroop lakshana and infinity. Consider a set T of triangles indexed by the entire set of real numbers, i.e. each triangle is labelled by a unique real number. Let (a,b) be the subset of all real numbers in between a and b, where a is less than b. Consider the subset S of triangles that are indexed by the set (a,b). Based on the previous discussion, the number of triangles in subset S is strictly one with the number of triangles in the entire set T. There is not even the slightest difference between the subset S (i.e. an attribute / roopa) and the entire set T because they contain the same number of triangles. Yet S is just a part of T and not the whole set T.
Let the set T be our representation of Brahman, the Supreme Lord. This is an appropriate representation due to the swaroop lakshana "satyam, jnanam, anantam, Brahman." Then a subset S is a particular roopa/attribute of the Supreme Being, like the Param Atma (not Jiva Atma) in each living being. Each roop is not a different being/person from Brahman. Each roopa of the Supreme Lord is His attribute as is strictly one with the entirety of the Supreme Being. This is also an important teaching of Shri Madhvacharya: when he says that there is a non-difference between Him and His roopas and attributes, he means that there is not even the slightest difference between Him and His roopas.
This teaching is reflected in the invocation mantra (purnam ada, purnam idam..) of the Isa-Upanishad. This teaching is also found in Shri Madhvacharya's commentary on the Katha Upanishad. Commentary on verses 10 and 11 of the 4th Vali reveals the following coexisting truths:
(1) Multiplicity of various forms of God is real
(2) No slight difference among forms (strict oneness)
(3) No slight difference between a form and the entirety of God’s being (I.e each form completely has all the infinitely auspicious attributes of God’s whole being)
(4) The forms do not have bhed-abhed (similar in quality but different in quantity, mundane part-whole relationship in which a part is less than the whole)
(5) God is a homogeneous being (each portion of Him is strictly one with His whole being)
This teaching of Shri Madhvacharya is also taught to Paingala by Sage Yajnavalkya with the words "Sa atma tattvamasi."
VI. The Paingala Upanishad and the Tattvavaad Shastra of Shri Madhvacharya:
The Paingala Upanishad is a minor Upanishad from the Shukla Yajur Veda and narrates Sage Yajnavalkya teaching his student Paingala. The venerable Sage Yajnavalkya teaches his student his own understanding of “Aham Brahmasmi” and “Tat Tvam Asi” in the third chapter. Consider the following verse which are taken from the first couple of verses from chapter 3. I used this link and this link as a guide to understand its meanings. The parentheticals help to guide the reader to understand the interpretation.


Then Paiṅgala asked Yājñavalkya to offer an exposition on the mahāvākyas (sacred sentences of the Vedas). To which Yājñavalkya replied: "One should scrutinize (the sacred sentences), Tattvamasi, Tvamtadasi, Twambrahmasi and Ahambrahmāsmi. The word 'Tat' denotes the cause of the universe that is variegated beyond perception, has the characteristics of omniscience, has Māyā as His vehicle and has the attributes of Saccidānanda. The very same Tat, when mixed up with the  antaḥkaraṇa (this refers to the activity of the individual Pāramārthika Jīva), produces the I-notion and so the very same Tat is the expressed meaning of ‘tvam.’




After rejecting Māyā and Avidyā (which hide the true nature of infinity and the swaroop lakshana and therefore suggest that the Pāramārthika Jīva roopa cannot be strictly one with the all-pervasive being), which are the vehicles of the Paramātmā and Jīvātmā (i.e. the Pāramārthika Jīva roopas),  respectively, the aim (or meaning) of the words Tat and Tvam is seen to be Brahman (the entirety of the all-pervasive Supreme Lord’s being), who is non-different (i.e. strictly one with or there exists not even the slightest difference) from the inner-Atma (Pāramārthika Jīva roopas).


Different people can use the same words to teach different facets of the ultimate truth. There is nothing strange about this phenomenon.  Thus using the Paingala Upanishad as evidence to refute Shri Madhvacharya's interpretation of the Chandogya Upanishad is futile and laughable. According to Shri Madhvacharya, and as seen from his commentary on the Brahma Sutras, the Parabrahman is "sarva-sabdha-vaacha," i.e. all words ultimately refer to the Supreme Lord. The subject of the third chapter of the Paingala Upanishad is Ishwara Param Atma only. The Jiva Atma exists separately from Him, but he is not the subject of the chapter. Why would a great sage like Shri Yagnavalkya teach his student to meditate on the Jiva Atma? Only meditation on Ishwara Param Atma will lead to moksha because only through tapas His grace will be attained. This chapter reveals the various names of the Supreme Lord such as "Aham," "Tvam," and "Jiva" to delineate His activities.
Ishwara Param Atma is called "Aham" because He is the Supreme Person amongst all persons: Aham Brahmasmi therefore means "Brahman is verily the Supreme Person named Aham" and therefore one should meditate on Him. **In this chapter, Sage Yagnavalkya reveals that the Supreme Lord is called Aham because He is the controller of the ahamkara mechanism, or ahamkara tattva.
The word “Tat” in  “Sa atma tattvamasi” refers to the all-pervasive Supreme Being Lord Shri Hari who is “the cause of the universe” and “has the characteristics of omniscience, has Māyā as His vehicle and has the attributes of Saccidānanda.” In other words, “Tat” refers to the entirety of the Supreme Lord’s being.
The word “Jiva” has been used by Sage Yajnavalkya to refer to the Supreme Lord who dwells within each organism, who is covered (but not affected by) avidya, and who carries the karmendriyas and jnanendriyas and the individual soul to the after life. The Supreme Lord is called Jiva because He is the controller and witness of life (Jivan) and the word “Jiva” is used to denote the Pāramārthika Jīva roopas. One such roopa resides in the body of each living being and is the bird that watches the other bird, as per the Mundaka Upanishad. The Pāramārthika Jīva roopa in each living being powers the antahkarana (and therefore the ahamkara) of that living being, leading to the creation of the “I” thoughts in the head. The words “Tvam” and “Aham” point to the “I” thoughts and the ahamkara, which further points to the Pāramārthika Jīva roopa in each living being who powers the ahamkara. The Pāramārthika Jīva roopas are the attributes of the all-pervasive Supreme Being and therefore they are the same Person. Consequently the “same Tat is the expressed meaning of ‘tvam.’” This is the teaching of the first paragraph: the same Tat Purusha who pervades everything is referred to by the words Tvam and Aham because He powers the ahamkara.
Avidyā refers to the ignorance and delusion present in a single body (and a single body is associated with one Pāramārthika Jīva roopa) while Māyā refers to the totality of delusion present in everyone in samsara. Both Avidyā and Māyā are forms of ajnana. Since jnana is associated with the knowledge of infinity as per the swaroop lakshana, ajnana must refer to the lack of knowledge of infinity. Ajnana hides the fact that a part/attribute can be strictly one with the whole and therefore hides the fact that there is not even the slightest difference between each Pāramārthika Jīva roopa/attribute and the entirety of the Supreme Lord’s being. Therefore, Sage Yajnavalkya teaches that when Māyā and Avidyā are removed, one realizes that “Brahman (the entirety of the all-pervasive Supreme Lord’s being)... is non-different (i.e. strictly one with or there exists not even the slightest difference) from the inner-Atma (Pāramārthika Jīva roopas).” This is the teaching of the second paragraph. It is intrinsically tied to the swaroop lakshana and therefore cannot be sublated. The teachings of the great seer Sage Yajnavalkya are in the language of infinity.
In today's society the belief that there is a God that is different from me is common knowledge due to the existence of Vaishnava Vedanta in India and Abrahamic faiths in other lands. However, several thousand years ago, this was not common knowledge. Purva Mimansa was a dominant school in ancient India and many students of scriptures were first taught the Purva Mimansa: Sage Jaimini's Mimansa Sutras begins with "Atha Dharma Jijnasa." Students were first taught dharma (swa-dharma, varnashrama dharma, etc). There was no notion of God but only gods. Only when the students transitioned from the Mimansa to the Vedanta were they taught about Brahman "Atha Brahma Jijnasa." So when a student was taught, "there exists a supreme independent being different from you" it was news to them because before, they learned only about dharma, rituals, and devatas.
The Advaitic interpretation can be dismissed by invoking their swaroop lakshana. Coincidentally, the Paingala Upanishad starts with "Brahman is infinite. Jagat is infinite" which is inextricably tied to the swaroop lakshana.
////**** Continued in a second answer ***** /////

/// Continued from part IX ///
An equally hilarious criticism was made by the venerable Swami Sarvapriyananda of the Ramakrishna Mission (I have nothing against Shri Ramakrishna. I believe he was a good man with a simple heart and an open mind who was unfortunately not exposed to Madhva Shaastra. Also, I have nothing against Swamiji personally. I still think he is a man with a good heart). In this video he says (from time 11:37 to 12:30), when discussing a time a Dvaita Pandit allegedly came to debate with an Advaitin, that Dwaita Vedanta is “known to a cow” and to tell him “something new.” Well, we note that Advaita’s unification through stratification is known even to children and the new thing the Advaitins need to know is their own swaroop lakshana. In another video, the same venerable Swami says there is “the seeing of the flower but no flower” because there “is no evidence that the flower actually exists.” And then he quotes some verses from the Vedas.
As Shri Madhvacharya beautifully and succinctly argues, we each have an intrinsic ability to discern truth. Perception and inference must be innately valid and the reality they present us with must actually and ultimately exist since such a position is the only one that allows us to know the contents of Scripture. Therefore, the world we see is real, though we may not be seeing the world as it really is. We can use a similar reasoning to convince ourselves that the external world exists independently of our observation of it. If the world does not exist independently of the mind (i.e. there is the seeing of the flower and but no flower) then there is the seeing of the Vedas but no Vedas. Since the Vedas are assumed to be pramanas, there is the seeing of the pramanas but no pramanas. How can the Vedas prove anything? A proof, or pramana, must exist independently of seeing it. There can be, in principle, no sufficient pramana that establishes that nothing exists independently from experience. When one argues that the absence of evidence is not evidence of absence, he assumes that evidence supporting his rejected views can exist in principle; however, when no such evidence can exist in principle to support his rejected views, he cannot appeal to the aforementioned argument. If something really is true then there will always exist, in principle, sufficient pramanas to bolster his claims. If there can never exist sufficient pramanas to establish the ultimate reality of solipsism/universal consciousness then the doctrine can never disprove the ultimate reality of duality. If solipsism/universal consciousness is the highest truth, the natural question is the following: how can the epitome of Vedic philosophy be unable to disprove its rival school? How can duality prove itself? From the swaroop lakshana.
Now let us ridicule these superficial words presented in a professional manner by posing the following questions to the Advaitins who claim to exist on the highest rung of knowledge.

Lord Ved Vyas, being the Supreme Lord Narayana in the Vyavarika satya of the Advaitins, could have easily told Shri Adi Shankaracharya the nature of uncountable infinity and bijections and reveal that the swaroop lakshana of the Advaitins challenges Advaita Vedanta since the nature of uncountable infinity reveals that strict oneness, strict difference, the existence of superiority and inferiority, and the existence of immutability and activity are not contradictory but complementary and coexist in the same level of reality. Because infinity is associated with truth the above cannot be sublated. Advaita Vedanta's tenet of various levels of reality that segregate "Tat Tvam Asi" from "Atat Tvam Asi" reveals a lack of knowledge on the swaroop lakshana and the thinking process of the Advaitins has errors. A doctrine based on errors, let alone one that does not even understand its swaroop lakshana, does not inarguably establish the true purport of the Vedas.


As per this biography, Lord Ved Vyas did not say this. Why did God not say this when He was fully capable of saying this?


Because the incident, as stated in the hagiography, did not happen. If it did and Shri Adi Sankaracharya was able to answer it, Shri Vidyaranya would have recorded such a momentous occasion in the Shri Sankara Vijaya and would have broadcasted to South Indian society what Advaita’s founder figured out centuries before the mlecchas rigorously constructed through mathematics.

The Advaitin swamis have dedicated their whole lives to “spirituality” but have been outpaced by the cow-eaters! And yet they vainly boast that they represent “THE Hindu tradition” by, among other ignorant things, presenting the illustrious and extremely educated devata Lord Shiva, who is eternally higher than all human muktiyogas, as a man who created a philosophy whose swaroop lakshana he did not understand! What a shame! What a shame! What a shame!
Luckily, Shri Madhvacharya knew infinity and preserved the honor of Aryavrat. It is a great pride of the Madhvas that their guru did not equate the highly respected Lord Shiva with the founder of Advaita.
There is a strong case to say that Shri Madhvacharya was the only Vedanta acharya who understood the essence of the verse Shri Adi Shankaracharya called the swaroop lakshana. These profound ideas and the swaroop lakshana defend the claim of his divinity.
As a former Advaitin who is humbled by the profound Brahma-Sutra Bhasya of the Tattva-vaad school, my message to the Madhwas is the following: Be proud of your parampara's divinity, never back down, and fight through scriptural debates for the sake of Shri Madhva till the end of Kali Yuga!
There is one God Ishwara Param Atma and in the land of Bharata, Shri Anandatirtha Bhagavadpadacharya was His chief (Mukhya) prophet.
All of the reasons outlined above are due to the grace of the Hari-Vayu Guru alone. I do not wish to take credit for it nor do I want anyone to give me credit for it.
bhāratīramaṇamukhyaprāṇāntargata śrī kṛṣṇārpaṇamastu

/// Continued from my answer posted on August 14, 2024  ///
VII: Looking at the Second Logic at the Foundation of Shri Adi Sankaracharya's Advaita Vedanta
In the following verses from his Brahma Sutra Bhasya, Shri Adi Sankaracharya differentiates between a swaroop lakshana and a tataksha lakshana, the latter being associated with activity and the former being associated with Brahman’s true nature:


This Sutra refutes that objection and gives a definition of Brahman: “That which is the cause of the world is Brahman” — where the imagined “cause of the world” is indicative of Brahman. This is called the Tatastha Lakshana, or that characteristic of a thing which is distinct from its nature and yet serves to make it known…The scriptures give another definition of Brahman which describes Its true nature: “Truth, Knowledge, Infinity is Brahman.” This is called the Svarupa Lakshana (Verse 1.1.12)


These arguments Shri Adi Sankaracharya betrays his beliefs that activity cannot coexist with Brahman’s nature. He believed that activity contradicted Brahman’s true description and therefore could not exist in the paramarthmika satya. He gives the following arguments in Verse 1.1.4:


Vedantin: No, since the Self cannot reasonably be the sphere of any action, for no action can take place without bringing about some change in its locus. But if the Self changes through action, It will be subject to impermanence, and that will militate against such texts as, "It is said to be immutable" (Gita II.25). And that is undesirable.


Shri Sankaracharya therefore argues that because activity and strict immutability are contradictory (“militate against”), they cannot coexist in the same level of reality and so Brahman is without any action. This is another fundamental logic that is at the heart of Advaita Vedanta. However, this claim is not true because activity and strict immutability can harmoniously coexist and the appropriate counterexamples come from infinity, which is Advaita’s swaroop lakshana “satyam, jnanam, anantam, Brahman.” Let us first consider uncountable infinity in one dimension. This will be a very simple system and will lay the conceptual groundworks for future discussions.
Consider infinitesimally thin vertical lines placed at each integer value on the real number line. The set of these vertical lines is a countably infinite set. Suppose the vertical lines move from the left to the right with uniform velocity. Although globally there is no decay since the number of vertical lines is always infinite, there is local mutability due to the introduced motion. For countable infinity motion and immutability are at odds with each other.
We note that for the countably infinite set of vertical lines, the cardinality of each proper subset is not always equal to the cardinality of the whole set. This means that if we zoom in enough, we will see the discretization in the dynamic system. Because of this innate discretization there is local mutability. The reverse is also true: local mutability leads to innate discretization and countability, resulting in the aforementioned cardinality property. Thus we conclude the following:

Cardinality of a proper subset not equal to cardinality of the whole set iff there exists a resolution in which the innate discretization and countability is seen iff there is no local immutability during motion.

If we consider the same one dimensional motion problem when the system is the entire uncountable and unbounded set of real numbers, we see that the first cardinality condition is not true. Therefore there does not exist a resolution in which discretization can be seen because the set is not discrete: it is uncountable and it is a mathematically proven fact that there does not exist a bijection between a countable infinite set and any uncountable infinite set. Therefore there is local immutability during motion. For uncountable infinity motion and immutability can occur together.
Of course, motion does not have to be simple in order for it to be compatible with local and global immutability. If we replace the aforementioned uniform rightward motion with uniform leftward motion, we again see immutability. Therefore, if the motion oscillates periodically (or aperiodically) between uniform leftward and rightward motions the resulting motion still leads to local and global immutability. Furthermore, the velocity value can change when there is a switch from one motional direction to another one and there will still be local and global immutability. These are more complicated examples of motion and they collectively reveal that for uncountable infinity immutability and activity, both simple and intricate, coexist.
Now let us consider uncountable infinity in two dimensions. Let each point in this space represent an infinitesimal particle. The set of all of these particles constitute the uncountable and unbounded set R^2 (2-dimensional real space). We see that uniform motion in any direction (x, y, and any linear combination of x and y) leads to local and global immutability in the system. Activity involving an arbitrary number of switchings among various directions of uniform motion will also lead to local and global immutability. Furthermore the motion of various individual infinite one-dimensional columns (or infinite two-dimensional strips or a mixture of both), each with uniform motion with a unique velocity, still leads to immutability. The same is true for the motion of various and separated individual one-dimensional loops (or two-dimensional circular strips, or both), each with uniform circular motion with a unique speed. For these latter cases, we see that the corresponding motions in a two dimensional countable infinite system, like a infinite square grid with points initially located at integer coordinates, does not lead to immutability due to the inherent discretization. We can consider even more intricate motions such as the uniform motion of a two-dimensional curved strip with the following structure: a straight half-infinite strip that soon curves in a quarter circular (or whatever fraction of a full circular path) way and then continues as another straight half-infinite strip pointing in a different direction. Such a motion again preserves immutability. Switchings between these various motions again preserves immutability.
Now we will consider an interesting motion found in the three dimensional case (the analogous activity in two-dimensions is obvious). From the study of uncountable infinity, the number of particles on the z-axis equals the number of particles contained within a cylinder of radius R1, and this equals the number of particles contained within a cylinder of radius R2 > R1. R1 and R2 can be arbitrarily large or small. We note that within each cylinder of arbitrary radius R1 > 0, there are countably infinitely many cylinders encased within. Now let us say all particles in the system will move with a uniform inward radial velocity. We demand that on the z-axis, the particles come to an instant halt and stick to the axis. Because these particles are infinitesimal, they occupy no space and thus can fit with the ones already on the z-axis. Particles initially on the z-axis do not move at all.
In the first case, we note that adding a number to (-infinity,+infinity) does not change the number of numbers in the resulting set because there exists a bijection between the set (-infinity,+infinity) and (-infinity,+infinity) U {1 point}. Thus adding any number of points, whether finite, countably infinite, or uncountably infinite, does not change the total number of points. Thus the number of particles on the z-axis never changes although an uncountably infinite number of particles land on every moment. Within each cylinder of arbitrary radius R, there is an uncountably infinite number of cylindrical shells within. Thus there is no change in the number of particles on a cylindrical shell of radius R at any instance in time.
These hypothetical scenarios on the motion of a “fluid” of uncountably infinite infinitesimal particles reveal that we can have a globally and locally static fluid whose constituent particles continuously move. In the realm of uncountable infinity seemingly contradictory concepts such as “the flow of time,” “motion,” “immutability,” “undecaying,” and “activity” are complementary. As a result, causality, knowledge acquisition, and immutability coexist since all contradictions are resolved in an entity that is an embodiment of uncountable and unbounded infinity. This is probably one reason we have the aforementioned verse in the Maitreya Upanishad:


“I am free of space and time, I am the bliss of the principal unclad sages, I am beyond ‘there is’ and ‘there is not’ and I am devoid of all negation.”


We discussed previously that this verse can be interpreted as Brahman’s words to Sage Maitreya. We can replace “there is” and “there is not” with “there is activity” and “there is no activity,” respectively; rewrite the above verse as I am beyond ‘mutability’ and ‘immutability;’ interpret it to mean that Brahman is beyond the contradictions the verses “there is activity” and “there is no activity” seem to imply; and realize that the previous scenarios of a static, but motional, fluid perfectly illustrate this verse.
Another important property of uncountable and unbounded infinity is immutability under any kind of replication. This shows that activity and immutability coexist harmoniously in Brahman, the embodiment of infinity. Consider a set of triangles whose cardinality is that of the set of real numbers: {▲_i : for i in the set (-infinity, +infinity)}. Here the subscript (i.e. the letter after the underscore) is to show that the cardinality matches that of the real numbers; the triangles are not actually identified with subscripts. Now suppose an uncountable number of triangles within this set are replicated. For instance, say that the subset {▲_i : for i in the set  (a, b)} replicates and so we have the new set {▲_i : for i in the set  (-infinity, _infinity) U (aj, bj)} where j is the imaginary number. Once again, the triangles are not actually identified with subscripts; they are used to show the replication. We see {▲_i : for i in the set (-infinity, +infinity)} and {▲_i : for i in the set  (-infinity, _infinity) U (aj, bj)} have the same number of triangles and so they are the same set. There is replication along with strict immutability. If we call the subset {▲_i : for i in the set (aj, bj)} a new body attribute/form we see that attribute/form creation through replication coexists with strict immutability. We also see that the new body attribute/form {▲_i : for i in the set  (aj, bj)} has the same cardinality as {▲_i : for i in the set (-infinity, +infinity)} and {▲_i : for i in the set  (-infinity, _infinity) U (aj, bj)} and all subset partitions of  {▲_i : for i in the set (-infinity, +infinity)} (and {▲_i : for i in the set  (-infinity, _infinity) U (aj, bj)}) can be completely mapped into the new attribute/form {▲_i : for i in the set (aj, bj)}. This property of uncountable infinity is reflected in the following verse in the Isaponishad’s invocation mantra:


पूर्णात्पूर्णमुदच्यते




Puurnnaat-Puurnnam-Udacyate


Now suppose there is attribute/form removal. From the set {▲_i : for i in the set  (-infinity, _infinity) U (aj, bj)} an uncountable subset of triangles is removed, say {▲_i : for i in the set (cj, dj)} which has the same cardinality as {▲_i : for i in the set  (-infinity, _infinity) U (aj, bj)} and all subset partitions of the set {▲_i : for i in the set  (-infinity, _infinity) U (aj, bj)} can be completely mapped into {▲_i : for i in the set (cj, dj)}. The resulting set has the same cardinality as {▲_i : for i in the set  (-infinity, _infinity) U (aj, bj)} and all subset partitions of {▲_i : for i in the set  (-infinity, _infinity) U (aj, bj)} can be completely mapped into the final set obtained after the removal of the subset {▲_i : for i in the set (cj, dj)}. Thus attribute/form removal coexists with strict immutability. This complementary property of uncountable infinity is reflected by the following verse in the Ishaponishad’s invocation mantra:


पूर्णस्य पूर्णमादाय पूर्णमेवावशिष्यते




Puurnnasya Puurnnam-Aadaaya Puurnnam-Eva-Avashissyate


Thus the Advaitin’s swaroop lakshana reveals that Brahman’s activities are ultimately real. The activities of Brahman coexist with His immutability due to the nature of uncountable and unbounded infinity. Since infinity is associated with truth in the Advaitin’s swaroop lakshana, it cannot be sublated. Thus the activities of Brahman cannot be sublated. Thus the verse Shri Adi Sankaracharya calls the swaroop lakshana refutes the previous claims sited from the Brahma Sutra Bhasya of the Advaita school.
Now let us review what I learned to be Shri Adi Sankaracharya’s Advaita Vedanta. There are different versions of Shri Adi Sankaracharya’s Advaita but the fundamental logic is the same across all variants.

We have shown that the two fundamental pieces of logic that are at the foundations of Advaita Vedanta are incorrect. Scripture alone can reveal the truth and that scripture that is logically flawless alone is true. The same is true for Bhasyas. Therefore Advaita cannot be true and the logical errors the school makes stem from their ignorance of their own swaroop lakshana which results from them relying on overday experience to draw their conclusions. Advaitins themselves mock Dvaitins for stating the obvious and using everyday experience, arguing that the Vedas cannot teach trivialities known to everyone due to everyday experience. Therefore, they classify Dvaita Vedanta as the lowest rung of Vedanta philosophy. Yet, the Advaitins themselves use everyday experience when interpreting Vedic texts and arriving at their non-dualistic conclusions. How are they the highest rung of Vedantic wisdom? How are they on the correct path?
VIII: Works of Shri Madhvacharya and Dwaita Scholars Revealing They Conceptually Knew Infinity and the Swaroop Lakshana of Advaita

(1) Shri Madhvacharya’s Brahma Sutra Bhashya Adhyaya 1, Pada 1, Verse 9


Section VII explains how “That is whole…the whole remains” is associated with infinity and the swaroop lakshana “satyam, jnanam, anantam, Brahman.” The above commentary by the great Shri Madhvacharya also describes how the creation and removal of roopas is not at odds with Shri Vishnu’s nature which is explained in Section VII.

(2) Shri Madhvacharya’s Brahma Sutra Bhashya Adhyaya 1, Pada 3, Verse 8


In this commentary, Shri Madhvacharya mentions how the Supreme Brahman Lord Vishnu is “unchangeable” that there “is no difficulty…of going out, etc, in virtue of His inconceivable powers.” Thus Shri Madhvhacharya states that for Brahman, activity and strict immutability are not contradictory, which was explored and demonstrated in Section VII.

(3) Shri Madhvacharya’s Brahma Sutra Bhashya Adhyaya 1, Pada 4, Verse 27


In this commentary, Shri Madhvacharya mentions how the Supreme Brahman Lord Vishnu “undergoes no change” and He “enters,...,shapes” prakriti. Thus Shri Madhvhacharya states that for Brahman, activity and strict immutability are not contradictory, which was explored and demonstrated in Section VII

(4) Shri Madhvacharya’s Brahma Sutra Bhashya Adhyaya 2, Pada 3, Verse 47 first paragraph


In this commentary, Shri Madhvacharya describes how each roop of the Supreme Lord Vishnu is strictly one with the entirety of Shri Vishnu. Section V addresses how this can be understood by using an uncountably infinite set, which we denoted as T.

(5) Shri Madhvacharya’s Brahma Sutra Bhashya Adhyaya 3, Pada 2, Verse 12


In this commentary, Shri Madhvacharya describes how each roop of the Supreme Lord Vishnu is strictly one with the entirety of Shri Vishnu and with each other roop of Shri Hari. He emphasizes roop-roop abheda and that each roop is purna (i.e. complete). Section V addresses how this can be understood by using an uncountably infinite set, which we denoted as T.

(6) Shri Madhvacharya’s Brahma Sutra Bhashya Adhyaya 3, Pada 2, Verse 13 beginning sentences


In this commentary, Shri Madhvacharya once again describes how each roop of the Supreme Lord Vishnu is strictly one with the entirety of Shri Vishnu and with each other roop of Shri Hari. He emphasizes roop-roop abheda and that each roop is purna (i.e. complete). Section V addresses how this can be understood by using an uncountably infinite set, which we denoted as T.

(7) Shri Madhvacharya’s Brahma Sutra Bhashya Adhyaya 3, Pada 2, Verse 25


Shri Madhvacharya rejects the idea that the manifestation of the Supreme, who is immutable and unmanifest, is actually an illusion by citing verses from the Puranas. He firmly believes that the appearance of God in front of devotees actually occurs and does not change the Supreme Lord’s immutability and eternal property of being unmanifest. In other words, according to Shri Madhvacharya and the Dwaita Vedantins, activity and immutability are not contradictory for God at all but are harmoniously coexisting features of God. The Supreme Lord, according to Dwaita Vedanta, is beyond the pair of opposites, a theme that is prevalent in the Avadhuta Gita of Sage Dattetreya and the Maitreya Upanishad.
This theme is completely on par with the nature of uncountable unbounded infinity. We had shown previously that the motion of a “fluid” of uncountably infinite infinitesimal particles reveal that we can have a globally and locally static fluid whose constituent particles continuously move. Furthermore, suppose this fluid could replicate itself, both locally and globally. Replication, either a local or global one, is an activity but the resulting number of particles in the new system is unchanged. Upon further inspection we see that, after local or global replication, invariance is true both locally and globally.

(8) Shri Madhvacharya’s Gita Tatparya Nirnaya Chapter 2, verse 18 (translated by Nagesh D. Sonde)



“Endowed with innumerable attributes, none is superior to Him. But those possessing noble eyes and ears and having fraternal feelings, become alike in mind with each other and with Him. Where all the desires are fulfilled in that state let me be delivered. By such words of separation with one another, the state of gradation (taratamya) is confirmed even after the deliverance “Where in deliverance everything has become even like the Self then whom does one see by whom ? Verily, when there (in that state of deliverance) he does not see, he is verily seeing, seeing though he does not see for there is no seeing. Because of (his being) imperishable there is none other than himself. There is nothing else separate from which he can see” – thus in Brihad Aranyak Upanishad. Consequently, with proper understanding the statements “Knowing the Supreme Brahman one becomes like Brahman”, “That, you are”, “I am Brahman” do not speak anything contrary to the scriptures.”


It is important to note that Shri Madhvacharya fully accepts that “Tat Tvam Asi” and “Aham Brahmasmi” are valid readings; however, when he comments on the Upanishads he provides alternate readings and meanings: “A Tat Tvam Asi” and “Aheyam Brahmasmi.” This means he accepts that the Vedas place equal emphasis on “Tat Tvam Asi” and “A Tat Tvam Asi” and that they harmoniously coexist in the same level of reality. How this can be modelled through infinity and describe the experience in moksha and ultimate reality are mentioned in Section III.

(9) Shri Madhvacharya’s Aitareya Upanishad Commentary:

In his commentary on his favorite Upanishad, Shri Madhvacharya explained how each form of the Supreme Lord Narayana contains all other forms of Lord Narayana in their entirety. This is also a property of uncountable infinity: for any partition of the set of real numbers, all of its members can be completely mapped into any subset (a,b). Therefore for the set of triangles indexed by the reals, each partition of the set of triangles, which corresponds to a partition of the set of reals, can be completely mapped to any uncountable subset of triangles, which corresponds to a subset (a,b).

(10) Shri Madhvacharya’s Katha Upanishad Commentary:

Commentary on verses 10 and 11 of the 4th Vali reveals the following coexisting truths:
(1) Multiplicity of various forms of God is real
(2)Creation of the various forms of God from God is real (also in chapter one of Mahabharata Tatparya) along with His absolute immutability.
(3) No slight difference among forms (strict oneness)
(4) No slight difference between a form and the entirety of God’s being (I.e each form completely has all the infinitely auspicious attributes of God’s whole being)
(5) The forms do not have bhed-abhed (similar in quality but different in quantity, mundane part-whole relationship in which a part is less than the whole)
(6) God is a homogeneous being (each portion of Him is strictly one with His whole being)
Based on the previous comments in sections V and VI it is easy to see how these truths reveal the nature of uncountable infinity.

(11) Sumadhva Vijaya by Shri Narayana Panditacharya: Chapter 7: The Description of Ved Vyas



“His body is composed of countless, complete auspicious qualities of the Supreme Soul, each one of which is infinite in number, extent, and nature. It has absolutely no defects and is essentially of the nature of Jnana (knowledge) and Ananda (bliss).” ~ Verse 24




“His consort Ramaa has been counting the infinite auspicious qualities of the lustrous nail of the little toe of His foot continuously (since eternity) and can never complete the count. Can anyone else ever be able to recite all His auspicious qualities?” ~ Verse 46


These verses reveal the Dwaita Vedantins’ belief that a small portion of God is just as large and endless as the entirety of God. This is perfectly on par with the mathematically proven fact that each bounded uncountable subset (a,b) of the unbounded and uncountable real numbers has the same number of numbers as the entire set of reals, which is used to reveal how a subset of triangles indexed by the set (a,b) contains the same number of triangles as the set of triangles indexed by the set (c,d) containing (a,b) and the set of triangles indexed by the set of reals.
We have shown that the works of the Dvaita scholars reveal they had a basic, but a fundamental, conceptual understanding of the properties of infinity. The Advaitins and their works clearly show their ignorance of infinity and their own swaroop lakshana. How can the Vedanta philosophers in the lowest rung know things that the philosophers in the highest rung never knew?
Because it is the Kali Yuga and the true Vedic tradition is being replaced with a new one claiming to be the old one.
IX: Addressing and Condemning Advaita’s Ridicule of Shri Madhvacharya (and Vaishnava Vedanta philosophy)
Ad hominem attacks are not by themselves bad and those interlaced with logic is admirable. When the latter type is subtly presented such that the receiving side does not see the logical points in between the words, it is a work of art. Such is the case for the Madhwa Amrutha Maharnava, a work composed by the venerable and unfortunately controversial Shri Narayana Panditacharya. Consider verse number 21:


[21] As per maayavaada there is no difference between wife and mother as all are equal. That person who tells this whenever he mates with his wife, [should know that] it's as good as mating with his mother.


At first glance, the author seems to be a perverted and illogical hater of the Advaita school, but those who think this way fail to understand how this attack is tied to the Mimamsa Sutras of Sage Jaimini. Shri Narayana Panditacharya points out that a true householder Advaitin should be comfortable in having intercourse with his wife and mother. If they are not, what is preventing them from carrying out the sin of incest? Dharma. Dharma (atha dharma jijnasa) is subtly reminding them that difference is ultimately real and that paap and punya ultimately exist. Shri Narayana Panditacharya cleverly, and controversially, points out through this sexually charged example that the feelings of reluctance point to the reality and unsublatability of duality.
Now let us consider some criticisms of Shri Madhvacharya and the Madhwa Shastra made by Advaita acharyas. Our previous arguments now allow us to comment on the venerable Advaitin Swami Maheshananda Giri’s statements on the various schools and acharyas of the Vedanta tradition. These statements can be found in this website and also in his introduction to the Chandogya Upanishad bhasya.


"We have been studying the different commentators, such as #Srikantha, #Ramanuja, #Vallabha, #Nimbarka, #Baladeva, #Srikara, #Madhva and the moderners, for over fifty years now. We have seen that apart from the criticism of the Advaita-view, there is little more in the content of their traditional view that is not found in Shankara, or is not just a logical corollary of what he has said. It is our challenge that apart from logic-chipping, not a single spiritual fibre, which has not been either supported or contradicted by Shankara, can be shown in the works of these commentators. All the statements of the other commentators about God, are melted down in the crucible of the concept of Saguna Brahman of Shankara.




The concept of Brahman of Srikantha and Ramanuja is practically identical with Shankara's concept of Ishwara, and they rarely try to contradict it. Similarly, Shankara's concept of Virat or Sutratman takes care of Madhva, Vallabha and others. Thus, what they contradict, is the range outside their vision. Had they been true traditionalists, they would have presented different facets of the same Truth which Shankara had presented. When it comes to presenting a positive aspect of the spiritual Being, they have little to say, though Being, they have little to say, though they roar to assert what it is not. But the traditionalist that Shankara was, he never criticized or disowned the views of #Virat, #Hiranyagarbha or #Ishwara. He rather developed complete harmony between them. Thus, without any fear of contradiction, we can say that Shankara's is THE Hindu tradition."


The main point these Vaishnava bhakti acharyas are making is that the Advaitic Brahman does not accurately represent the Vedic Brahman. When Advaitins themselves are making errors when understanding the true, absolute, and non-sublatable nature of the Supreme, what qualifications do they have to say that the verses the Vaishnava acharyas cited to establish their own siddhanta  reflect Brahman as He is ultimately not and that their (the Advaitins’) understanding reveal Brahman as He really is? All verses describe Brahman as He ultimately is and the so-called contradictory themes present in the Vedic texts are there to reveal that they are not contradictory but complementary and that they harmoniously coexist in the ultimate reality. The so-called inclusivity of Advaita hides the blatantly ironic and embarrassing fact that it unifies the Vedic verses through stratification. All the Advaitins do is  place Vedic themes that seem contradictory to everyday experience into different levels of reality like ordinary children and portray themselves as the most spiritually mature and the best representatives of “THE Hindu tradition.” It is a lamentable tragedy that Aryavrat has descended into such superficiality and stupidity, but what can we do because it is the Kali Yuga.  Such pseudo-unification and pseudo-“it all fits” approaches go against the true and intricate meanings of “ananta” in the Advaita Vedanta’s swaroop lakshana. The “it all fits” approach adopted by Advaita is asuric, not daivic, and cannot sublate the reality that reflects the true meanings of the swaroop lakshana and “ananta.” Shri Madhvacharya’s Dwaita Siddhanta is THE Hindu tradition and a doctrine that does not even understand the meaning of its own swaroop lakshana is a concocted system wholly unworthy of being listened to. Can any Advaitin dare to say that great personalities like Sage Dattatreya (from the Avadhuta Gita) and Lord Shiva (from Maitreya Upanishad) did not understand the true nature of infinity?
/// will continue ////
