How can non_advaitins criticize Advaita without going beyond what Advaita seems to be saying at the word-level?
Shankara says: "these passages are meant to teach the true nature of Brahman and therefore do not convey the meaning they literally seem to"
It is TRIVIAL to refute "Aham Brahmasmi" - the person attesting it is a finite human subject to old age, disease and death - and he/she obviously cannot be Brahman.  "Aham Brahmasmi" is actually a shortcut or metaphor for a deeper truth that can only be approximately put into words - words that only act as pointers.
Have criticisms of Advaita by Ramanuja and Madhwa actually gone beyond the superficial meaning of Advaitic assertions?
For example, a good refutation might say "I went to an Advaitic guru and realized the truth he taught me.  It was a transcendental, blissful experience - but I got the same experience by taking a drug.  Therefore, Advaita is only an attempt to attain an illusory state of omnipotence.  After the transcendental state goes away - you are back to mundane existence with its tribulations".

Advaita realisation is permanent

if it has not been asked already, please ask it as a question @CracklingCyclone

@SK "Have criticisms of Advaita by Ramanuja and Madhwa actually gone beyond the superficial meaning of Advaitic assertions?"Yes, their criticisms of Advaita are not trivial. Shri Madhvacharya's doctrine reflects the true nature of the verse Shri Sankaracharya calls the swaroop lakshana of Brahman: "satyam, jnanam, anantam, Brahman." The logical reasoning used by Shri Shankaracharya to interpret "Tat Tvam Asi" contains a subtle, but important, logical error and the reasoning is not on par with his swaroop lakshana.

@SK The non-sublatability of duality and Shri Madhvacharya's interpretations follows from Advaita's own swaroop lakshana. If duality cannot be sublated then Advaita cannot be ultimate reality. See here (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/60178/refuting-sa-atma-atat-tvam-asi-of-madhava-paingala-upanishad/60282#60282)

@SK By the way you said Advaita is "a transcendental, blissful experience." Advaita is not an experience because experience requires the existence of an experiencer and an object being experienced. There is no such thing as an Advaita "realization." There is no such thing as an Advaita "sadhana"

That is a just a word-game.  the word "realization is an approximate rendering what happens when Jiva-Brahma Aikya occurs. @Debbie please try to be respectful and not try to score "wins" for your team.

@SK I was not trying to be disrespectful or score wins. I only posted my answer when someone, perhaps unintentionally, tried to be disrespectful and score wins. Peace brother.

@Debbie Rope continue to exist in front of a realised as well as a deluded person. A realised person knows that it is rope but deluded person thinks it is a snake. The same logic can be applied for existence of experiencer and object being experienced.

@CracklingCyclone No it cannot. Sabdha pramana and anumana pramana solely can be used to show that prataksha is a paramarthmik pramana. Duality can be established by using the swaroop lakshana and the swaroop lakshana describes reality. If duality can be sublated then so too can the swaroop lakshana. How is that possible? I agree with you that prataksha pramana should not be assumed to be ultimately true a priori, but prataksha can be logically proven to be ultimately real a posteriori via sabdha and anumana.

@CracklingCyclone And by anumana I mean logically interpreting scriptural passages not deducing from everyday experience. See the link I shared to see what I am trying to say.

@CracklingCyclone "Rope continue to exist in front of a realised as well as a deluded person. A realised person knows that it is rope but deluded person thinks it is a snake. " --- I am aware of this analogy, brother. I am a former Advaitin

@Debbie please check Bhagavad Gita 5.8-9 "enlighted person always thinks, “I am not the doer,” even while engaged in seeing, hearing, touching, smelling, moving, sleeping, breathing, speaking, excreting, grasping, and opening or closing the eyes. With the light of divine knowledge, they see that it is only the material senses that are moving amongst their objects.

This type of not thinking we are not the doer is what making the person thinks perceived objects in the relative reality as unreal @Debbie

@CracklingCyclone Thinking "I am not the doer" also means thinking "I am an instrument through which God does things." The article "the" in "the doer" stresses independence and hence God is called "the doer." Hence thinking "I am not the doer" means thinking "God alone is the doer because He does things independently, i.e. at His own free will." Also "This type of not thinking we are not the doer is what making the person thinks perceived objects in the relative reality as unreal" is not always true. This type of thinking can also make people think about the absolute independence of God.

@Debbie //This type of not thinking we are not the doer is what making the person thinks perceived objects in the relative reality as unreal" is not always true.This type of thinking can also make people think about the absolute independence of God // this is not what the Bhagavad Gita says. If you read the verses carefully it actually means an enlightened person always knows that only the material senses are engaged with their objects and that he is different from them.

@CracklingCyclone Ok, thanks for point that out...but nevertheless the verse, read the way you gave it, also shows the reality of the difference between the senses, the object of the senses, and you. One who continues to think that he is not the doer can continue to still think the reality of the senses, the object of the senses, the individual soul, and the difference among these things.

@CracklingCyclone Also, the words "material senses" in the phrase "material senses that are moving" refers to the gross senses, their devas and to God who is controlling them. In Shri Madhvacharya's Bhasya on the Aitareya Upanishad (see the one prepared by Prof K. T. Pandurangi or the Sanskrit ones found on internet archive), he writes that Lord Vishnu's Vasudeva rupa resides in and drives the senses/jnana indriyas. Shri Madhvacharya also mentions that there are three ways to interpret Vedic verses: adhyatmika (here it means monotheistic), adidaivic (here it means polytheistic), and adiboutic.

@CracklingCyclone The adiboutic interpretation of "they see that it is only the material senses that are moving amongst their objects" is exactly what you pointed out. In the adidaivic interpretation, the words "material senses" refers to the abhimani devatas who manage the sense organs. In the adhyatmika interpretation, "material senses" refers to the Vasudeva roopa who is controlling them as the sole independent reality. Hence the Gita verse you cited does refer to the absolute independence of God who is THE doer.

@CracklingCyclone You will need to give other verses to inarguably illustrate non-duality. The word "eka" means "two, different, inferior/superior" and and is in line with the verse Shri Sankaracharya calls the swaroop lakshana because when one understands a little bit of infinity one sees how in infinity seemingly contradictory concepts such as strict oneness and strict difference (i.e. the existence of superiority and inferiority) coexist in harmony. The swaroop lakshana of Advaita points solely to Shri Madhvacharya's Siddhanta. And only his works show an understanding of infinity.
